# Joomla 3.2 Grouped List Custom Field List doesn't have SELECTED value

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am trying to create a custom field form for template parameter for Joomla 3, by following instruction from this page 
[Creating a custom form field type](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type)

Here are my codes :

```
class JFormFieldMy extends JFormField {
protected $type = 'my';
public function getInput() {
                return '<select id="'.$this->id.'" name="'.$this->name.'">'.
                        '<optgroup label="First">'.
                            '<option value="1">One</option>'.
                            '<option value="2">Two</option>'.
                            '<option value="3">Three</option>'.
                        '</optgroup>'.
                        '<optgroup label="Second">'.
                            '<option value="4">Four</option>'.
                            '<option value="5">Five</option>'.
                            '<option value="6">Six</option>'.
                        '</optgroup>'.
                       '</select>';
        }
}
```

It works good, the value is saved, but the selected value doesn't have the selected="selected" state so the dropdown list will always show the option 'One' when I choose / the actual value is  'Two'

I have read this solution : [Joomla 2.5 Custom Field List not SELECTED in display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439922/joomla-2-5-custom-field-list-not-selected-in-display) but that's for generic list type not for grouped list I wanted.

Anyone can help me? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the selected element of the list:

```
<option value="the_value" selected>....</option>
```

Another approach: instead of deriving your class from JFormField you should derive it from the abstract class JHtmlList (you will find it on `libraries/cms/html/list.php`)
You may start taking `libraries/cms/form/field/limitbox.php` as an example.

Comment: Hi @Pep thanks for the hint. But that's exactly my question, how can I put that 'selected' to the selected option. I'm not good with php so I think I won't go with your suggested JHtmlList solution

Comment: Well my problem is exactly the same with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439922/joomla-2-5-custom-field-list-not-selected-in-display?rq=1 , the difference is I want to create a grouped list while the solution for genericlist.

Comment: Why are you making a new field type instead of just using the existing grouped list type?